# Is there a Newsletter module which send mails even to main category subscribers when mails are sent to child category subscribers

Tags: drupal-7, newsletter

I am new to Drupal and I am in need of a News Letter module.
Right now in my project we have Main categories and Sub Categories. 
Eg: Web Development is the main category and 
    Java, HTML, CSS , Javascript etc are it's child categories.

If a user is subscribed only to IT(main) category and when the mails are being sent to Java subscribers, I need he mail to be sent to the user subscribed to IT as well.

How can I do this?

Right now we are using SimpleNews module. But this does not do what we want.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module you can trigger emails under any condition you want. In general you have Events Conditions and Actions:

**Events:**

*something happens* it could be "After saving new content of type"

**Conditions**

Content is of type (let say) blog

**Action:**
Send an e-mail   (and here you need to fetch data - your list of subscribers)